# Shocking Singing Logic

Tags: mathematics, word, enigmatic-puzzle

$B =  (\lnot C \land E) \land A$
$A = (\lnot E \lor D) \land *$
$D = \lnot A \land \lnot(B\lor E)$
$C = \lnot(E \lor B) \land (A \lor D)$
$E = (A \lor \lnot C) \land (* \land D)$

TRUE / FALSE

**What am I?**

Comment: And the task is to find the hidden word?

Comment: Oh whoops, forgot the question

Comment: Is the star a wildcard, or does it mean 'all', or is that for us to figure out?

Comment: That's for you to figure out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> The Australian rock band **AC/DC**

Because there are two different arrangements that make all of the statements true, which are (in order of A, B, C, D, E, *)

> 1,0,1,0,0,1
>  and
>  0,0,1,1,0,0

> The first solution has one A and one C, and the second solution has one D and one C. Therefore, when we assign True to the star, we get AC and when we assign False to the star, we get DC. Together, that makes AC/DC, which explains the title well with the double meaning of AC/DC (band - singing) and AC/DC (alternating current/direct current - shocking)

Comment: Sadly the answer isn't correct, once you find it you'll get confirmation from the title

Comment: Precisely, this type of puzzle is slightly derived from the "Superlogic" formula

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "superlogic" formula. Also, please delete your first comment, now that I have edited my answer.